# How to change the text size in pop-up window

Tags: javascript, html, popup

My Question:- I have a content in parent window it's very and i displayed corner of a page i want print that part of a page, so i opened a popup window in that font should be 22px

```
function CallPrint(strid)
{
 var prtContent = document.getElementById(strid);
 var WinPrint =    window.open('','','letf=0,top=0,width=1,height=1,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
 WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);
 WinPrint.document.close();
 WinPrint.focus();
 WinPrint.print();
 WinPrint.close();
}

<div id="content">
 <strong style="font-size:9px">This is the content i am going to print, 
but here it is very small font. In this page i have lot of information 
so i want to print a part of page. Which is displayed in this div. </strong>
</div>
<input type="button" value="print" onclick="CallPrint(strid)">
```

I got a answer but that is not working

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding the question. Did you try changing `font-size:9px` to `font-size:22px`?

Comment: ya, in parent window it should be 9px but in popup window i need 22px.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to achieve that but there is one :

```
WinPrint.document.write('<span style="font-size:22px">' + prtContent.innerHTML + '<span>');
```

It would be better to use valid html and a specific css for printing.

Comment: hello sir this is not working can you plz give other suggestion