# how to change font of text in confirm navigation popup?

Tags: javascript, html

I just want to change the font of a text which is written on this popup like size of a text
 e.g `font-size:16px;`

How is it possible ?

```
<html>
     <head>        
        <script>
            window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
              return 'You application form is not submitted yet.';           
          };
        </script>
     </head>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to style default confirm box with only css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185152/how-to-style-default-confirm-box-with-only-css)

Comment: Maybe this link can help you:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139546/how-to-change-the-text-size-in-pop-up-window]

Comment: answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620516/how-to-get-text-bold-in-alert-or-confirm-box